# Получить историю сообщений группы через telegram api

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Я знаю что у телеграма есть метод `messages.getHistory`, но как его использовать?
Офф. доки мне ничего не говорят.

Или это вообще не относится к `api` для ботов? Знаю, что есть способы сделать что-то подобное при помощи `telebot` и ему подобных, однако не хочется отказываться и под них переписывать большой кусок кода...

Кажется, телеграму просто посылать запросы вроде `/getMe` или `/setWebhook?<params>`, а в случае `getHistory` копипаст не катит.

Comment: прошу прощения, не могу оставить комментарий, так как не хватает рейтинга. получилось ли у вас найти способ? (ответ удалю позже)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После долгих поисков я так и не смог найти идеального для себя решения ввиду его, как выясннилось, отсутствия. Однако при помощи костылей таки получилось получить желаемый результат, правда в не совсем удобной форме, но все же лучше, чем ничего :)

[Ссылка на статью, на которой базируется весь ответ](https://proglib.io/p/pishem-prostoy-grabber-dlya-telegram-chatov-na-python-2019-11-06)

Не вижу смысла расписывать код (смотрите статью), но выделю

**Ключевые моменты:**

- как я понял, бот НЕ УМЕЕТ доставать историю с каналов/чатов/помоек, НО такая штука, как `telegram application` вполне подходит для данной задачи
- после, выгрузив историю, можно как обычно мониторить при помощи вебхуков или getUpdates обновляя базу (или для чего вам нужна была история)

Проблема только в том, что возвращаемые данные в непривычном формате и для парсинга нужно дополнительно попотеть (особенно файлы, их только через пересылку сообщения можно использовать)...

Жаль, что мне никто так и не ответил, но надеюсь, что хоть кому-то я смог помочь.

Comment: Спасибо, ты сэкономил мне кучу времени)